# Remove column name from legend in pandas barplot

Tags: pandas, bar-chart

I have a dataframe as below

```
        batsman      non_striker  partnershipRuns
0      SK Raina       A Flintoff               23
1      SK Raina         DR Smith               90
2      SK Raina     F du Plessis               36
3      SK Raina        JA Morkel               14
10     MS Dhoni    CK Kapugedera               18
11     MS Dhoni         DJ Bravo               51
12     MS Dhoni     F du Plessis               27
13     MS Dhoni        JA Morkel               12
14     MS Dhoni         JDP Oram                6
```

I have been able to create a stacked bar plot using

```
df1=df.groupby(['batsman','non_striker']).sum().unstack().fillna(0)
df1.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True,legend=True)
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))
```

This results in the column name being included in the legend as a tuple as shown in figure.[image]

How can I not have the column name and just have the value for the legend?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For prevent `MultiIndex` in columns specify column for sum after `groupby`, also `fillna` here is not necessary, add parameter `fill_value=0` to [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1=df.groupby(['batsman','non_striker'])['partnershipRuns'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Another solution with [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df1=df.pivot_table(index='batsman',
                   columns='non_striker',
                   values='partnershipRuns',
                   aggfunc='sum',
                   fill_value=0)
```

Comment: Thanks. I used the pivot also, but I seemed to get the tuples, though not exactly the way you have mentioned. Your solution also works!

Answer (score 1):

An easy fix for you, would be to do :

```
df1=df.groupby(['batsman','non_striker']).sum().unstack().fillna(0)['partnershipRuns']
```

instead of :

```
df1=df.groupby(['batsman','non_striker']).sum().unstack().fillna(0)
```

Why ? Because your aggregations are creating a MultiIndex. And when you are plotting, you could have different multiIndexes values (here, multiple values instead of one being "partnershipRuns").
If you want something else because I didn't understand your question correctly, just ask.